# ROUND function in mySql giving strange result after using TRUNCATE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, rounding, truncate, sqldatatypes

I am using a stored procedure in mysql to set the following value to a double variable.

```
 DECLARE vVar DOUBLE(16,2) DEFAULT 0;

 SET vVar = ROUND(TRUNCATE((29.00 * 1.75/100),2));
```

Firing the above expression in mySql editor gives 1 (which is correct, since ROUND(0.50) would give 1). However, the value that gets stored in vVar is 0.

On the other hand, if I write

```
SET vVar = ROUND(TRUNCATE((29.00 * 1.75/100),4));
```

then the value that gets stored in vVar becomes 1. (which is also correct, since ROUND(0.5075) is 1).

Could someone please explain the strange behavior occurring here.

I had a doubt regarding the datatype of vVar, so I tried changing it from DOUBLE(16,2) to DECIMAL(16,2). But it did not make any difference.

Is there a way to get 1 from the first expression ?

```
 SET vVar = ROUND(TRUNCATE((29.00 * 1.75/100),2));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `However, the value that gets stored in vVar is 0` ... how are you determining the value stored in `vVar`?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : I am using this value to update a column in a table

Comment: I would suggest that you provide a reproducible demo of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Yuck!

Keep in mind that `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` numbers are stored in *binary*, not *decimal*.  This means that everything else you are doing in that expression needs to be converted between binary and decimal one or more times.

0.5075 *cannot* be represented exactly in `DOUBLE` -- with, or without the (16,2)

`DOUBLE(16,2)` adds an *extra* rounding, namely to 2 *decimal* places before storing into the *binary* `DOUBLE`.

My head spins.

I hope yours does, too.

Enough for may rambling...  When I try variations on your `SET`, I get `1`.  I did not build a Stored Proc; I suspect something else is wrong in the SP.  Perhaps you could build a complete test case for us to work with??  Also, what version of MySQL are you using -- in the unlikely case that something is broken in that version.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @ScottHunter - It may not.  But, once the OP gets away from the rounding problems the issue may go away.